# Como adicionar uma biblioteca JAR em um projeto Java sem IDE?

Tags: java, jar, windows-8, biblioteca, jfreechart

Salve. Estou tendo dificuldades em adicionar a biblioteca JFreeChart em meu projeto Java (utilizo o Windows 8). Eu já descompactei o JfreeChart, mas não sei o que fazer a partir daí. Como sou um programador old school e ainda uso Notepad, não consegui achar nada no Google que me ajudasse.

Muito obrigado.

Comment: Caso ainda precise de ajuda, por favor edite sua pergunta e adicione o código da classe, a mensagem de erro exata, os comandos executados e em qual diretório ele foi executado e, finalmente, os locais onde estão os arquivos (classe, jar, etc.). Abraço!

Comment: Muito obrigado cara! Mas acho que já consegui resolver esse problema (só não me lembro como). Abraços!

Answer (score 2):

Você deve ter esquecido uma dependência, especificamente:

**jcommon-1.0.23.jar** 

*(rev. 1.0.23 pode variar, essa vem com o ultimo release do JFreeChar)*

Você encontra a informação da dependência na [pagina de download do JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/download.html):

> JCommon Dependency JFreeChart requires the JCommon class library. The
>   JCommon runtime jar file is included in the JFreeChart download --- if
>   you require the source code for JCommon (recommended), you need to
>   download this separately.

```
javac -classpath jfreechart.jar;jcommon-1.0.23 CompileMe.java
```

Recomendo utilizar [alguma IDE Java](http://www.eclipse.org/ide/) para facilitar seu trabalho.

Answer (score 1):

Tu precisa passar o `classpath` na hora de executar o `javac`

```
javac -classpath jfreechart.jar minhaClasse.java
```

Comment: Ele fala que o pacote não existe : /

Comment: eles estão na mesma pasta?

Comment: que erro exibe?

Comment: Sim, estão. Ele diz que o "package jfreechart does not exist" (só pra constatar:o nome desse jar possuía também a versão do mesmo, a qual eu retirei). Já adicionei o caminho para o jar no classpath, mas nada resolve : /

Comment: sua classe está com package?

Comment: Não. Só com o import jfreechart.*; que coloquei no início e a classe em si. Não sei se é uma informação útil, mas eu copiei apenas o JAR para o diretório com a classe.

Comment: Experimenta `javac -cp ".;jfreechart.jar" minhaClasse.java`

Comment: Ainda nada. Porém, percebi algo: se eu retiro o Import, a classe compila com o comando que está na resposta. Eis minha pergunta: usando esse comando, o import continua necessário? Ou quando eu compilo dessa forma eu "já importo automaticamente"?